# Custom projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am working on an agricultural planning project in which field workers specify areas for certain uses and provide me the dimensions and locations relative to survey markers, in feet. I want to add those to a layer in QGIS. Other layers have satellite tiles and property boundaries. So to accommodate this I created a custom projection that I use for my field-data layer. The project CRS is WGS 84 (EPSG:4326). It seems to work but QGIS does not recognize that the units of my layer are "feet" (it says "unknown") so I worry about calculating things like area within the layer that uses my projection.

My question here is why aren't the units showing up as "feet" and is there a better way to do this?

In creating my custom projection, I took a built-in one (WGS 84 / UTM zone 4N, ESPG:32604) and changed the false northing and false easting to reset the origin to my survey marker, and changed the CS East and North axes to have units of "feet" rather than "metre". Here is the new WKT string:

```
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 4N Lot1 feet",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 4N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-159,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",-280784,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",-2316100,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["feet",0.3402]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["feet",0.3402]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World - N hemisphere - 162?W to 156?W - by country"],
        BBOX[0,-162,84,-156]]]
```

Comment: Length unit for Foot (international) is 0.3048. QGIS uses Proj, so it should be interpreting the false easting/northing units correctly, but you could try changing them to use feet as well.

Comment: The project units are feet but for some reason parts of QGIS where I use this CRS, it thinks the units are "unknown", for instance, creating a grid on a vector layer. It makes me think something is wrong with the CRS definition.